# How can I make/receive phone calls with a modem on Linux?

Tags: linux, phone, dial-up, api, call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I receive phone calls on a Linux server and script stuff depending on the numbers pressed?](https://superuser.com/questions/451550/how-can-i-receive-phone-calls-on-a-linux-server-and-script-stuff-depending-on-th)

This is related to my previous question ([How can I receive phone calls on a Linux server and script stuff depending on the numbers pressed?](https://superuser.com/questions/451550/how-can-i-receive-phone-calls-on-a-linux-server-and-script-stuff-depending-on-th)) which I consider unanswered. I was pointed to asterisk. I've asked over at their forum but their solutions are too expensive ($400..). [Link to forum thread](http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=83568).

I still want to script stuff over the phone. It has to be reachable from a regular phone and I don't want to pay for any additional services. So no VoIP I guess.

On Windows there seem to be a dialer built-in (*dialer.exe*). I don't know what a dialer exactly is but I've googled around and it looks like some people actually use it to make phone calls. Is there something similar on Linux?

So how do I make/receive phone calls with a modem on Linux? Is there an API so I can do that programmatically?

Comment: I don't see how this question is functionally different from your original one?

Comment: I want to use a modem this time. If I update the previous question, does it get bumped? I want the question to be visible.

Comment: Editing a question bumps it to the front page, yes. You can also consider placing a bounty on it to have it featured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to identify whether you are using a hardware modem or a winmodem. A hardware modem has jumpers on it that set IRQ, for example. To your Linux box it will appear to be a serial port. If what you have is a winmodem, you will need a driver to configure the modem.

That said, if what you have is a hardware modem, it'll be easy to communicate with. Most hardware modems use a [Hayes instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#The_basic_Hayes_command_set). If you are using a hardware modem a scripting language can pass control arguments to it, and use the modems built in ability to understand DTMF to pass output back to the scripting language.

I think anything outside of what I've answered would be more suited to another forum.  You've asked several questions, and I have entire books on this subject.

Comment: I have not bought the modem yet. I've looked at the Hayes instruction set. You can ask your modem to dial a number, fine. But how do I get the raw 8khz sound?

Comment: I believe you turn the speaker on:

Mn  -  "Set Speaker Mode"

    M0  -  Disable speaker

    M1  -  Enable speaker until a carrier signal is detected

    M2  -  Enable speaker

    M3  -  Enable speaker after dialing but disable after a carrier signal is detected

Then you would have to use a sound card (run the speaker out to the Mic on the sound card being careful to ensure you don't overdrive the input).

Comment: @Everett: Is there not any open-source software which already implements all this that you mentioned?